# Header link in Jquery mobile not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using the following on a mobile site but when I click the home button I simply get the loading circle and the page I am trying to get to never resolves:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" style="height:50px; padding:3px;">
    <img src="/m/images/logo2.png">
    <a href="/m/" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" 
       data-direction="reverse">Home</a> 
</div>
```

This is the version I am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you are using absolute path in your href you can't use it like this:

```
<a href="/m/" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" 
   data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
```

You need to point it to your domain page:

```
<a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" 
   data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
```

Or to you inner page:

```
<a href="#index" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" 
   data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
```

**data-direction="reverse"** will only work as a back transition but unlike **back-btn="true"** here you need to provide a real and existing href.